# Forward declaration error when migrating code from openssl 1.0.1 to 1.1.0

Tags: openssl, forward-declaration

I have a codebase that was moved from openssl 1.0.1 to 1.1.0. One Project in it is producing errors when compiling.
Some parts do compile without error but I stumbled upon forward declaration errors:

```
Foo/BarDH.cpp:37:28: error: member access into incomplete type 'dh_st'
        nRes = BN_bn2bin( key->pub_key, &keyout[0] );
                                  ^
/usr/local/sysroot/usr/local/include/openssl/ossl_typ.h:104:16: note: forward declaration of 'dh_st'
typedef struct dh_st DH;
```

This is how files are included:

**BarDH.cpp:**

```
#include BarDH.hpp
[...]
```

**BarDH.hpp:**

```
#include <openssl/bn.h>
#include <openssl/dh.h>
#include <openssl/ec.h>
[...]
class BarDH{
    BarDH(void);
    virtual ~BarDH(void);

    enum
    {
     MAX_PUBKEY_SIZE = 2048 / 8
    };
    DH* key;
};
```

Did anything change in how one is supposed to include files form openssl 1.0.1 to 1.1.0 or can anyone see what's going on here?
Thank you!

Comment: OpenSSL 1.1.0 made most structures opaque, so you are no longer allowed to directly access the members of the DH struct. Use `DH_get0_pub_key(key)` to get hold of the pub_key value instead of `key->pub_key` on line 37 of BarDH.cpp

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. maybe post it as answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSL 1.1.0 made most structures opaque, so you are no longer allowed to directly access the members of the DH struct. Use `DH_get0_pub_key(key)` to get hold of the `pub_key` value instead of `key->pub_ke`y on line 37 of BarDH.cpp

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/DH_get0_pub_key.html

Comment: Is there a way to make those structures accessible again in openssl 1.1.1? Or do I have to change my entire code?

Comment: No, you cannot make them accessible. You must change your code.